# how to compare two successful results in jmeter for response format json with one empty result aslo applicable

Tags: java, json, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have to compare two json response as successful response in JMETER.

For example either I will get a response with values,

```
[
    {
        "id": 423082,
         "createdBy": 10000,
         "createdOn": "03/11/2016 12:04 PM"
    },
    {
         "id": 423083,
         "createdBy": 10001,
         "createdOn": "06/11/2016 12:04 PM"
    }
]
```

OR I will get an empty json `[]`

Both are successful results for me.

How can I compare these results in Response Assertion or JSON Path Extractor as successful results.

Comment: improve formatting

Comment: how precise you want to be in the case the data is returned? Because simplest solution would be something like `\[(\{.*\})*\]` - checks whether it's a JSON array with 0 or more objects inside. But it can be as fancy as checking whether date is valid and so on...

Answer (score 0):

[image]Create one regular expression extractor with regex `\[(.*?)\]`and give some variable name like `checkpoint` now apply a response assertion and pass `${checkpoint_g0}`, so that if your response does not have any value than also it'll check for `[]` empty json otherwise it'll compare whole response

Comment: Hey its not working. I created one regular expression extractor with reference name = checkpoint and Regular Expression = \[(.*?)\] and then in my response assertion selected 'contains' and pattern to test ${checkpoint_g0}. But still its not matching when I am getting empty json []. And I have to even compare 'createdBy' so that even when json is not empty its still valid

Comment: regular exp should be \[(.*?)\], provided response should not have any new line, else share your exact response over here

Comment: My response is [] There is no space or new line.

Comment: Sorry but its not working :(  Are the other things right ? response assertion and all. I am new to JMETER

Comment: Does the order matters ?

Comment: yea order matters, first apply regular exp extractor then response assertion as a child of request for which you want to validate. also place one debug sampler to check is your correlation working

Comment: I have tried both of them. Still its not working. I guess something else is going wrong

Comment: Not working. In response assertion where are we suppose to pass ${checkpoint_g0} ?

Comment: check attached image